# Repeating jQuery code and adepting

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
var flag=true;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("glavna").mouseenter(function(){
        if(flag)
        {
            $(".ocenjevanje").animate({right:"+=440", bottom:"+=20"},1000);
            $(".svetovanje").animate({right:"+=440", top:"+=140"},1000);
            $(".onas").animate({left:"+=440", top:"+160"},1000);
            $(".infotocka").animate({left:"+=440", bottom:"+=3"},1000);
            flag=false;
        }
    });
});

var bannana=true;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".glavna").click(function(){
        if(bannana)
        {
            $(".ocenjevanje").animate({right:"-=440", bottom:"-=200"},1000);
            $(".svetovanje").animate({right:"-=440", top:"-=140"},1000);
            $(".onas").animate({left:"-=440", top:"-=150"},1000);
            $(".infotocka").animate({left:"-=440", bottom:"-190"},1000);
            bannana=false;
        }
    });
});
```

This moves the cards i have in the middle of the page to the side with hover over the main card and returns them on click. But the problem is i can only do this one time (only one time hover and click....after that it does nothing). How can i make the code so i will be able to repeat this actions? And how can i adept jQuery on all screen sizes, so the cards will be always on the corners of the screen no matter its size? And the last thing, cards that go to the top animate little diferent for no reason. They don't go from their starting position like cards on bottom but move slightly top before animating diagonally. How can i fix that?
If needed here is the full code (with css and html): http://jsfiddle.net/kkdpw/

Comment: Well, the reason it only works once is because of the flags `flag` and `bannana` that are being set.  Once the `.glavna` classed item is clicked, those two both become `false` and the code in the `if` blocks will no loner run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change flag and banana back to true/false after the event..

```
var flag=true;
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".glavna").mouseenter(function(){
  if(flag)
  {
     $(".ocenjevanje").animate({right:"+=440", bottom:"+=20"},1000);
     $(".svetovanje").animate({right:"+=440", top:"+=140"},1000);
     $(".onas").animate({left:"+=440", top:"+160"},1000);
     $(".infotocka").animate({left:"+=440", bottom:"+=3"},1000);
     flag=false;
      bannana = true;
  }

});
});

var bannana=true;
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".glavna").click(function(){
  if(bannana)
  {
     $(".ocenjevanje").animate({right:"-=440", bottom:"-=200"},1000);
     $(".svetovanje").animate({right:"-=440", top:"-=140"},1000);
     $(".onas").animate({left:"-=440", top:"-=150"},1000);
     $(".infotocka").animate({left:"-=440", bottom:"-190"},1000);
     bannana=false;
      flag = true;
  }

});
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/kkdpw/5/)

Comment: That works but another problem appears. Every time i repeat hover and click, cards go to different position. How can i set it so they will always go to and return to same point?

Comment: that is because you are animating the right to `+=440` and bottom to `+20` this means each time this is adding 440px to its right and 20 to bottom ... make it static .. and it will stay in same posiyion

Comment: But how do i make it static? Im sorry but im so confused right now. I feel like i dont know anything anymore lol. Can you please fix it in my fiddle? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: ok here you go.... http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/kkdpw/8/ .. commented `//here` in lines that i made chnages

Comment: Oh and do you know why on first animation top cards animate different?
They seem to move a little top then on the side. Do you maybe know what the problem is here?

Comment: @Urrby hehe.. :).. ok here you go again..;).. fixed css.. check out the comment in css..that is where i made the changes...:)  http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/kkdpw/14/